# Разбить список на строки по символу разделителю

Tags: python, строки

Есть список из лемм:

```
['\ufeff', 'джордж', ' ', 'находиться', ' ', 'где-то', ' ', 'в', ' ', 'темнота', '\n', ' ', 'блейза', ' ', 'не', ' ', 'мочь', ' ', 'он', ' ', 'разглядеть', ' ', 'но', ' ', 'голос', ' ', 'доноситься', ' ', 'громко', ' ', 'и', ' ', 'четко', ' ', 'грубый', ' ', 'чуть', ' ', 'хрипловатый', '\n', ' ', 'по', ' ', 'голос', ' ', 'всегда', ' ', 'казаться', ' ', 'что', ' ', 'джордж', ' ', 'слегка', ' ', 'простужать', '\n', ' ', 'что-то', ' ', 'с', ' ', 'он', ' ', 'происходить', ' ', 'когда', ' ', 'он', ' ', 'быть']
```

Как можно разбить список на строки по символу `/n` ?

Пример результата:

```
джордж находиться где-то в темнота
блейза не мочь он разглядеть но голос доноситься громко и четко грубый чуть хрипловатый
по голос всегда казаться что джордж слегка простужать
что-то с он происходить когда он быть ребенок
джордж никогда не говорить что именно но адамов яблоко пересекать полоска шрам
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lst = ['\ufeff', 'джордж', ' ', 'находиться', ' ', 'где-то', ' ', 'в', ' ', 'темнота', '\n', ' ', 'блейза', ' ', 'не', ' ', 'мочь', ' ', 'он', ' ', 'разглядеть', ' ', 'но', ' ', 'голос', ' ', 'доноситься', ' ', 'громко', ' ', 'и', ' ', 'четко', ' ', 'грубый', ' ', 'чуть', ' ', 'хрипловатый', '\n', ' ', 'по', ' ', 'голос', ' ', 'всегда', ' ', 'казаться', ' ', 'что', ' ', 'джордж', ' ', 'слегка', ' ', 'простужать', '\n', ' ', 'что-то', ' ', 'с', ' ', 'он', ' ', 'происходить', ' ', 'когда', ' ', 'он', ' ', 'быть']
print(*lst)
```

Comment: У меня не сработало. Он не разделил по /n

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы по /n оно уходило на новую строчку

Comment: @irina2020 все исправил